# I want to install jsreact but when i run this code: I get this error where as i have update the **tar** version

Tags: reactjs, npm, npm-install, yarnpkg, tar

**npm install -g create-react-app@1.5.2**

> npm WARN deprecated tar@2.2.2: This version of tar is no longer supported, and will not receive security updates. Please upgrade asap.

**npm install tar@6 -g**

> changed 7 packages, and audited 8 packages in 2s found 0 vulnerabilities

Comment: StackOverflow is for programming questions only. This sounds more like a question for https://SuperUser.com -- assuming you're asking about upgrading tar, and not about something else.

Comment: @JamesZ: why is that? Jsreact is clearly a tool used by developer. Problems with developer tools that don't directly involve programming are on-topic on SO.

Comment: @AsadAli: First, what you get is a *warning*, not an error. That usually means that things will continue to work, but it's something you should look at. Second: you posted how you updated the tar package. Did anything break when you did that? If not: what other question do you still have? If something did break: show us what and how. [Edit] your question to include those details.

Comment: @GenerousBadger As I mentioned, if the question is about **upgrading tar**, then it's really not a programming question. And the question itself does not mention any issues with jsreact, it talks only about tar upgrade

Comment: @JamesZ: the error message is clearly about the [npm tar package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tar) and not just the normal user-level `tar` program. And the warning pops up when installing create-react-app. Without posting actual program code, it can't get more directly programming-related than this.